# How to defend against a Live USB computer hack

Tags: linux, boot, security

A Linux installation can be simply hacked by using a live USB/CD, gaining root access on the live distro, chrooting to the target filesystem and running `passwd root`. One can use grub [too](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Step_by_Step_Guide/s1-q-and-a-root-passwd.html). There may be some other methods as well.

What is the most efficient way of defending against hacking the installation from Live USB provided the system runs on an SSD drive (TRIM and encryption are said not to work well)?

Comment: Johansson's Immutable Laws of Security #3: If a bad guy has unrestricted physical access to your computer, it's not your computer anymore.

Answer (score 7):

Don't allow USB access.

Truth is that if someone has physical access to the machine, there's not a lot you can do. In this narrow case your best bet is to disable booting to USB and lock the BIOS (or whatever EFI setup utility is being used) with a password. It's a bit like putting a pad lock on a garage door, there are ways around it, but it's an easy step that keeps honest people honest.

Comment: And use a grub password and a hardware kensington lock

Comment: @Nils Nice one! I always forget the grub password.

Answer (score 5):

There is really only one answer to this: full disk encryption.

The way full disk encryption is usually done with Linux, your `/boot` partition is not encrypted and contains the kernel and initramfs — just enough functionality to start a minimal environment that prompts you for the passphrase to decrypt the root filesystem and get access to everything else.

Full disk encryption done this way will protect your data from being observed by someone who boots an alternate operating system, or who for that matter extracts your hard drive and mounts it on another system. It will *not* protect you from someone who boots an alternate operating system or who mounts your hard drive elsewhere and installs a malicious binary/kernel/module in your `/boot` partition, in your bootloader, or in your system firmware.

> TRIM and encryption are said not to work well

Yes, because TRIM would reveal which parts of the disk are in use and which are not. There isn't really a way around that...

Comment: Full disk encryption is a good answer, I just have never liked it. Is the information your trying to protect really that sensitive? An questions like that.

Comment: @coteyr peace of mind... and you can feel free to reuse/sell/give the hard drive to a stranger after you have finished using it (say, after an upgrade or decommission of the machine) if it has never seen a plaintext byte.

Comment: When `/boot` is unencrypted, the kernel can be replaced without notice. I don't have a solution, just saying...

Comment: @sebix The solution to that is the large can of big fat worms known as secure boot.

Comment: Full drive encryption is must-have but not sure it addresses the problem if you machine is on and you are logged in. If I lock the screen and walk away is it still safe or can someone walk up with a USB stick and steal my data?